# send object as parameter in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

sorry for my newbie question.

I'm sending current_user helper that have User object type as resque job runner parameter like this

```
      JobRunner.run LikerCommenterAnalyzerJob, current_user, session['basic_instagram_data']['access_token'], 505
```

but when I try to get current_user parameter in perform method of resque it changed to Hash type

```
def self.perform (current_user, access_token, archive_id)

account = current_user.InstagramAccount.where('access_token', access_token).first

end
```

and my error is

```
undefined method `InstagramAccount' for #<Hash:0x007f9e39c27458>
```

Comment: i wrote my error :) `undefined method 'InstagramAccount' for #<Hash:0x007f9e39c27458>` @sawa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you push a task to resque, it will store somewhere to run later (Redis for example). So it can't store your object, it just stores the description of your passed parameters, the `Hash` above is the description.

Then `Resque` pulls down the description to run it.

So the solution will be, put the information that you use to retrieve the object instead (this is best practice)

**When pushing the task:**

```
JobRunner.run LikerCommenterAnalyzerJob, current_user.id, session['basic_instagram_data']['access_token'], 505
```

**When runing the task**

```
def self.perform (user_id, access_token, archive_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  account = user.InstagramAccount.where('access_token', access_token).first
end
```